# How to convert an array to JSON?

Tags: php, json

I am having array in this format.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => User Name
            [1] => User Email
            [2] => User Mobile
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Anjali
            [1] => anjali@gmail.com
            [2] => 9945587526
        )

)
```

and i am looking a json

`{"1":"user name","2":"user email","3":"user mobile"}`

Comment: there's a function, called `json_encode`, rtfm!

Comment: The OP claims he/she looking for *keys as numbers*, not an array - answers should take this into account, or at least mention it.

Comment: what about 2nd array ?

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

> Returns a string containing the JSON representation of value.

```
echo json_encode($array);
```

Also `json_encode` is available in **php > 5.2.0**

Also you may try this:

```
$json = array2json($data);
```

Also note that Array in JSON are indexed array only and PHP Associatives array are objects in JSON

Answer (score 3):

You need [**json_encode**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), but to include the keys of the array, you need to set the `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT`
option *(available in PHP >= 5.3.0)*.

```
echo json_encode($arr, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

[**See demo**](http://3v4l.org/gFR9v)

Answer (score 1):

Use function [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Example:

```
echo json_encode($your_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

  $your_array = array(
                      0 => array(
                                    0 => "your name",
                                    1 => "your email",
                                    2 => "your mobile"
                                ),
                      1 => array(
                                    0 => "Anjali",
                                    1 => "Anjali@gmail.com",
                                    2 => "999999999"
                                )            
                   );

foreach($your_array as $key=>$arr)
{
     $arr_temp = array();
     $i=0;
     foreach($arr as $k=>$v)
     {
        $i+=1;
        $arr_temp[$i] = $v;
     } 
     echo json_encode($arr_temp);
     echo "<br/>";
}

?>
```

**OUPUPT :**

```
{"1":"your name","2":"your email","3":"your mobile"}
{"1":"Anjali","2":"Anjali@gmail.com","3":"999999999"}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://eval.in/175068)**